# Integral Inequality Absolute Value: $\left| \int_{a}^{b} f(x) g(x) \ dx \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|\cdot |g(x)| \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, absolute-value, integral-inequality

Suppose we are given the following: $$\left| \int_{a}^{b} f(x) g(x) \ dx \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|\cdot |g(x)| \ dx$$

How would we prove this? Does this follow from Cauchy Schwarz? Intuitively this is how I see it: In the LHS we could have a negative area that reduces the positive area. In the RHS the area can only increase because we take the absolute values of the functions first.

Comment: What type of integration are you dealing with?  Lebesgue or Riemann?

Comment: @nrpeterson Does it make a difference?

Comment: His level and what he knows about integration make a difference in how I would explain a proof of the inequality, yes.

Comment: @nrpeterson: Riemann.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to expand both sides to their Riemann sum definitions and apply the triangle inequality?

Comment: The key fact is that if $f \le g$ then $\int f \le \int g$.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The big idea here is this:

First: it is enough to show that
$$
\left\lvert\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right\rvert\leq\int_a^b\lvert f(x)\rvert dx,
$$
since you can replace $f(x)$ by $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ to get the desired result.

Now, notice that
$$
-\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq f(x)\leq \lvert f(x)\rvert
$$
for all $x$; hence
$$
-\int_a^b\lvert f(x)\rvert\,dx\leq \int_a^b f(x)\,dx\leq\int_a^b\lvert f(x)\rvert\,dx.
$$
Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Since $|x| \leq a \Longleftrightarrow -a \leq x \leq a$, we have the desired result.

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: Is $a < b$ assumed?

Comment: @user124384 since we are integrating over the interval $[a,b]$, the convention is that $a<b$.

Comment: @fourierguy I think, it would be better to use a different letter than "a". It got me confused with the boundary of the integral for a while.

Comment: does this theorem have a specific name?

Comment: @JoãoBravo it's essentially the continuous version of triangle inequality

Comment: I don't get why $|x|\leq a$?