# Show that the inequality $\left|\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx\right| \leq \frac{1}{12}$ holds for certain initial conditions

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, proof-writing, solution-verification, integral-inequality

> Given that a function $f$ has a continuous second derivative on the interval $[0,1]$,  $f(0)=f(1)=0$, and $|f''(x)|\leq 1$, show that $$\left|\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\right|\leq \frac{1}{12}\,.$$

My attempt: This looks to be a maximization/minimization problem. Since the largest value $f''(x)$ can take on is $1$, then the first case will be to assume $f''(x)=1$. This is because it is the maximum concavity and covers the most amount of area from $[0,1]$ while still maintaining the given conditions.

Edit: Because of the MVT and Rolle's Theorem, there exists extrema on the interval $[0,1]$ satisfying $f'(c)=0$ for some $c\in[0,1]$. These extrema could occur at endpoints.

Then $f'(x)=x+b$ and $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+bx+c$. Since $f(0)=0$, then $c=0$ and $f(1)=0$, then $b=-\frac{1}{2}$. Remark: Any function with a continuous, constant second derivative will be of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ and in this case, $a=-b$ and $c=0$. Now,  $$\begin{align*}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(x^2-x)\,dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg]_{x=0}^{x=1}\\&=-\frac{1}{12}\end{align*}$$

Next, we assume that $f''(x)=-1$ and repeating the process yields $$ \begin{align*}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(-x^2+x)\,dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{-x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg]_{x=0}^{x=1}\\&=\frac{1}{12}\end{align*}$$ Thus we have shown that at the upper and lower bounds for $f''(x)$ that $\frac{-1}{12}\leq\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\leq \frac{1}{12} 
 \Longleftrightarrow \left|\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\right|\leq\frac{1}{12}$ because $f''(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

I was wondering if this was 'rigorous' enough to be considered a full proof and solution to the problem.

Comment: Why must the cases $f''(x)\equiv1$ and $f''(x)=-1$ necessarily give the extreme values for $\int_0^1|f(x)|\,dx$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Not sure. It just felt like the natural thing to assume. It actually works out if you assume $f''(x)=x$.

Comment: "Not sure." This is why I only see here a "plausibility argument" but not a proof.

Comment: I’m sorry, but it’s not. You don’t prove the existence of a maximum (which isn’t obvious), you don’t provide a satisfactory explanation about why said maximum must satisfy $f’’= \pm 1$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yea. I think if $f''(x)$ is any function which meets the criteria, then the inequality will hold. You just have to find what input value gives the maximum and minimum output values for the second derivative on the interval. So my choice of a constant function was in the set of valid functions.

Comment: @Mindlack how would one go about doing that? By just considering a function that exists and meets the conditions?

Comment: @Mindlack C Squared has the right intuition. Though it is not a proof, it is correct to try extreme values by Pontryagin's maximum principle.

Comment: @Crystomath: I’m not denying that it’s a good idea to try extreme values. I’m just saying that, *a priori*, there’s no given rigorous argument why 1) they would be optimal; 2) they would be the only optimal solutions; 3) infinite-dimension phenomena (eg it’s a sup, not a max) cannot occur. All three issues can probably be resolved, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)f^{\prime\prime}(x)\, dx. $$

By integrating by parts twice, you get

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)f^{\prime\prime}(x)\, dx = \underbrace{\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)f'(x)\bigg|_0^1}_{0} - \int_0^1\bigg(x-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)f'(x)dx=$$$$= - \int_0^1\bigg(x-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)f'(x)dx= \underbrace{- \bigg(x-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)f(x)\bigg|_0^1}_{0} + \int_0^1f(x)dx$$
Therefore,
$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\, dx = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)f^{\prime\prime}(x)\, dx}$$

Now use the following [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429220/integral-inequality-absolute-value-left-int-ab-fx-gx-dx-right):
$$\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx\right| \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)||g(x)|\, dx$$

Since $g(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x}{2}$
is the expression you got, this should yield the desired result.

$$\left|\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\right|=\left| \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)f^{\prime\prime}(x)\, dx\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}|x^2-x|\,dx=\frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: @Csquared is there a problem so that you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: Well, the problem is proving existence of a maximum and why the maximum must satisfy $f''(x)=\pm1$ You used part of my attempt, which uses an invalid claim.

Comment: @CSquared You asked, "*I was wondering if this was 'rigorous' enough to be considered a full proof and solution to the problem.*" and I think you got enough reactions for this in the comments above. And I wanted to provide a rigorous proof...

Comment: @CSquared VIVID's solution gives an upper bound on the absolute value of the integral.  That's all the problem asks to be shown.

Comment: @CSquared VIVID has shown $|\int f|\le\int|g|=\frac{1}{12}$, and $g''=\pm1$.

Comment: @VIVID Super sorry, I didn't make the connection for the absolute value of $f''(x)=1$ in the last step. I guess I am still a bit confused on what you integrated by parts in the first step. I know you're not wrong, its just I can't get my answer to match up with yours. Did you differentiate $f(x)$ and integrate $1$?

Comment: @CSquared Better try to prove that the RHS is equal to LHS by integrating by parts.

Comment: @VIVID When I integrated by parts, the left hand side was $xf(x)-(f’(x)x^2)/2 +\int( f’’(x)x^2)/2 dx$. I am confused because I got $g(x)$ on the baseless assumption that $ f’’(x)=1$ yielded an extrema.

Comment: @CSquared See the edit for the integrating process.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\text{Taylor}$ we can get:
$$
f\left( 0 \right) =f\left( x \right) -xf'\left( x \right) +\frac{f''\left( \xi _1 \right)}{2}x^2,\xi _1\in \left( 0,x \right) 
$$
$$
f\left( 1 \right) =f\left( x \right) +\left( 1-x \right) f'\left( x \right) +\frac{f''\left( \xi _2 \right)}{2}\left( x-1 \right) ^2,\xi _2\in \left( x,1 \right) 
$$
so we can get:
$$0=2f\left( x \right) +\left( 1-2x \right) f'\left( x \right) +\frac{f''\left( \xi _1 \right)}{2}x^2+\frac{f''\left( \xi _2 \right)}{2}\left( x-1 \right) ^2$$
i.e.$$2f\left( x \right) =\left( 2x-1 \right) f'\left( x \right) -\frac{f''\left( \xi _1 \right)}{2}x^2-\frac{f''\left( \xi _2 \right)}{2}\left( x-1 \right) ^2$$
then we can get:
$$2\int_0^1{f\left( x \right) \text{d}x}=\int_0^1{\left[ \left( 2x-1 \right) f'\left( x \right) -\frac{f''\left( \xi _1 \right)}{2}x^2-\frac{f''\left( \xi _2 \right)}{2}\left( x-1 \right) ^2 \right] \text{d}x}$$
after simplification,we can get:$$4\int_0^1{f\left( x \right) \text{d}x}=-\int_0^1{\left[ \frac{f''\left( \xi _1 \right)}{2}x^2+\frac{f''\left( \xi _2 \right)}{2}\left( x-1 \right) ^2 \right] \text{d}x}$$
so$$4\left| \int_0^1{f\left( x \right) \text{d}x} \right|\leqslant \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1{\left( 2x^2-2x+1 \right) \text{d}x}=\frac{1}{3}$$
i.e.$$\left| \int_0^1{f\left( x \right) \text{d}x} \right|\leqslant \frac{1}{12}$$